# using remote MS Access database which connects to remote SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2008, microsoft-access

We have a Microsoft Access database + application (on Server A) which connects to a remote SQL server (Server B) using System DSN ODBC connection (on Server A) to the SQL database server.

The users are open this Access database remotely as it is on a shared location on the server A. They still have to create a local ODBC connection on their computers to connect to Server B.

Is there anyway that they can access the Access database and **not** have to create a local ODBC connection?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate the need for the local DSN on each machine by using a bit of code in the Access database. You do of course still need the appropriate ODBC driver installed but I expect the one you need is probably standard on Windows anyway.

A local DSN will be required to initially create the database.

The following in what I use for dynamically relinking to a MySQL database, so you will need to edit it accordingly. The code is called from the AutoExec macro or can be run manually or from a form.

Note that this is not my code but I've been using it for a very long time and don't recall where I originally got it. All I've done is edit it to suit my requirements.

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function ReLinkTables()

Dim dbPUBS As DAO.Database
Dim tdfPUBS As DAO.TableDef
Dim strTable As String
Dim strConnect As String
Dim InFile As Integer


' Set the following variables tosuit your DB connection
Dim Server As String
Dim Database As String
Dim User As String
Dim Password As String

On Error GoTo 0
Set dbPUBS = Nothing
Set dbPUBS = CurrentDb
strConnect = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};" _
    & "SERVER=" & Server & ";" _
    & "DATABASE=" & Database & ";" _
    & "UID=" & User & ";" _
    & "PWD=" & Password & ";" _
    & "OPTION=" & 1 + 2 + 8 + 32 + 2048 + 16384

' Refresh Access linked tables
For Each tdfPUBS In dbPUBS.tabledefs
    ' Only attempt to refresh link on tables that already
    ' have a connect string (linked tables only)
    If Len(tdfPUBS.Connect) > 0 Then
        strTable = tdfPUBS.Name

        ' Set the tables connection string
        tdfPUBS.Connect = strConnect

        ' and refresh the link
        tdfPUBS.RefreshLink
    End If
Next

' Refresh Connect String for all Pass-Through Queries
'strMsg = "Refreshing links for all Pass Through Queries."
'DoCmd.Echo True, strMsg
'For Each qdfPUBS In dbPUBS.QueryDefs
    'If Len(tdfPUBS.Connect) > 0 Then
        'qdfPUBS.Connect = strConnect
    'End If
'Next
```

End Function

Comment: I have included this function by updating and then updated macro to run this function when we open the database. It is still asking for the ODBC connection.

Comment: @Manjot, that suggests either the syntax or driver might be incorrect for your connection. The driver name is particularly fussy and must match perfectly, including case sensitivity.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a DSN when you define the link to the SQL Server.  Instead specify the actual connection string (should be an option, but I haven't worked with Access for years).